# How to play this B on Oboe

Tags: practice, fingering, oboe

[image]

As you can see, there is a B flat (or A sharp), but I am asking about the same note, B without flat (or A without sharp)

What's the fingering on Oboe?

#### Note

I think that I can play it the same as normal B but with the octave key. In other words, with the left index finger and the octave key, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct- it's the same fingering as an octave lower, with the octave key added. But there are lots of fingering charts online.  Here's one: http://www.oboesforidgets.com/fingerings/oboechart.pdf

Comment: The note is played with the **second** octave key unless the oboe is full automatic.